# Nest pseudo class like hover/focus into a hyperlink with LESS

Tags: css, less

I use LESS.

How can I say that the hover/focus belongs to the first `> a` can I somehow put the hover/focus inside the `> a`?

```
 > ul > li > a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    > a:hover, > a:focus { // login, register
        background-color: @navbar-background-color;
    }
```

Comment: Nest it within the first rule and use the parent selector (like `&:hover, &:focus {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LESS's Parent Selector (`&`)](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) to include selectors belonging to the current selector:

> The `&` operator represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing selector.

```css
> ul > li > a {
    ...

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        ...
    }
}
```